# Pass data through form by onclick

Tags: forms, codeigniter, onclick

This should be something really simple but I just can't get it.

I want to pass a particular field value to controller function through onclick by form submit.

```
      <form action="<?php echo base_url();>data/pass" method="post">
  <select  name="name1" id="name1" onclick="" class="m-wrap" >
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>

            <option value="1">by year</option>        
        </select>                     
 <form>
```

Comment: Would `onchange` be a better option?

Comment: can we use onchange=this.value

Comment: `onchange="somefunction(this.value)"...` ... `function somefunction(val) { alert(val); }`

Comment: I want to go the function specified inside the form

Comment: `onclick`, `onchange`, and so on are JavaScript events, so you'll need to trigger the form action through JavaScript code. For example, add `document.getElementById("myform").submit();` to `somefunction()` above.

Comment: i got the instruction is that post data through the form,wrie something inside onclick()

Comment: Actually, the simplest way is just to add `onchange="this.form.submit()"`... you could try `onclick="this.form.submit()`, but I'd imagine this would cause problems in some/all browsers because as soon as you click, the form could submit, even before you get a chance to select a value. Try it and see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91233/discussion-between-rose-and-michael-mcmullin).

Comment: Better to continue it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code like this

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>data/pass" method="post">
    <select  name="name1" id="name1" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="m-wrap" >
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
        <option value="1">by year</option>        
    </select>                     
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <form id="form-id" method="post">
      <select  name="name1" id="name1"  class="m-wrap" >
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>

                <option value="1">by year</option>        
            </select>   
<button type="submit" >Onclick</button>                  
     <form>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

        $(document).ready(function(){

               $('#form-id').ajaxForm({  
              type : 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              url: "<?php echo base_url();>data/pass ",
              success: function(res) 
              {  
                //Your code success
              } 
            });
        </script>``
```

You Can use this form

Comment: u want  used ajax in onchange call function